# load select options from file html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file, ng-options, html-select

I'm working on a project and I need to save the options of a `<select>` bar `<options>` in a file, and load them from there.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<select id="washprogram" onchange = "setProgram.call(this, event)">
    <option disabled id = "Keuze maken" selected="selected">Make your choice</option>
    <option id="Whites">Whites/option>
    <option id="Coloureds">Coloureds</op<tion>
    <option id="Textile">Textile</option>
    <option id="Create your own">Create your own</option>
</select><br/>
```

Now I need to save the options in a .txt file, and load it from there. After that I need to create extra options, but I think I'm able to do that myself.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add the relevant code and we'll help you debug it.

Comment: A file? What file? One on the computer hosting the browser? One of the computer hosting the server? Does it really need to be a *file*? Or does it just need to be stored somewhere? What have you got so far? At the moment you have presented us with a spec for a JavaScript program and nothing else, so you would be better off on a website for hiring freelancers. You should narrow down your question to a specific problem.

Comment: I tried to save my options like they are there, and then use #include with php. I tried to save them like just words, and load them with javascript. But than I'm unable to add more than 5

Comment: "I tried to save my options like they are there" — how? "I tried to save them like just word" — how? "and load them with javascript" — how? "than I'm unable to add more than 5" — Why not? Do you get any errors?